# how to load sqlite3 in windows 10?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am a newbie with sqlite3 and trying to use it in windows 10. At first, I download it from website, ofcourse there was no problem. Then I put it at `C:\`, the name of the folder was `sqlite3`.

Then I add this code into `environment variable` : `C:\sqlite3`, I thought that it could help sqlite run.

Then, I tried to run sqlite3 by this code `C:\sqlite3`, but I could not run it.

I am very confuse, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: If the folder was `C:\sqlite3` the the program might be `C:\sqlite3\sqlite.exe`. Look in the directory for files ending with `.exe` and run the one that's named like sqlite or sqlite3.

Comment: @karmakaze in my folder, there are 3 files named `sqldiff`, `sqlite3` and `sqlite3_analyzer`, so i must run the file `sqlite3` to make something new ?

Comment: Yes, but you should first make and go into a directory you want to use as your project working folder. From there, run `C:\sqlite3\sqlite3 mydata` where you can use any name instead of `mydata`. This will create the file mydata.sqlite3 (or the name you picked). Depending on the version the file extension may be different (.db, .dat, .sqlite).

Comment: @karmakaze : thank you very much. by using your comment  now i can make my own data. Thank you.